# install package from tar.gz in Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I got *.tar.gz file and how to install that package in conda virtual environment ?

I've tried the following:

```
$ source activate env01
(env01)$ conda install /installers/anaconda/cassandra-driver-3.11.0.tar.gz
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - cassandra-driver-3.11.0.tar.gz

Current channels:
...
```

If I use pip install, it wasn't stored in environment directory. See below:

```
(env01)$ pip install /installers/anaconda/cassandra-driver-3.11.0.tar.gz
Processing /installers/anaconda/cassandra-driver-3.11.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9 in /dataplatform/software/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cassandra-driver==3.11.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: cassandra-driver
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cassandra-driver ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/linknet/.cache/pip/wheels/e9/ff/17/ebfd2f04dfac5206db48c1520c6f669ec225ddc2c192aada17
Successfully built cassandra-driver
Installing collected packages: cassandra-driver
Successfully installed cassandra-driver-3.11.0
```

My conda env01 directory is: /dataplatform/software/anaconda/envs/env01

Comment: Is the .tar.gz file a conda package? How did you get it/from where did you download it?

Comment: I got that file from pypi

Comment: Then why would you expect that conda would install it? Regarding your edit, did you install Python into that environment? Why are you installing from files instead of letting conda download all the dependencies?

Comment: My bad, i'm relatively new in conda and didn't get the concept at the beginning. Now I'm able to install the package from source. The purpose is using conda without connecting to internet.

Comment: When you do `pip install`, are you using the copy of pip that corresponds to conda env01?

Comment: @user3080953 yes, my problem was I didn't clone 'base' env to the new created env, so there was no pip installed in new env directory. It's solved now. See my edit.

Comment: If you've answered your own question, please add it to an answer instead of editing the question. This lets other people with the same problem know it's solved and lets you accept your own answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it by cloning conda env from base and install the package.

```
$ conda create -n env01 --clone base
Source:      /dataplatform/software/anaconda
Destination: /dataplatform/software/anaconda/envs/env01
The following packages cannot be cloned out of the root environment:
 - conda-4.4.10-py36_0
 - conda-build-3.4.1-py36_0
 - conda-env-2.6.0-h36134e3_1
Packages: 238
Files: 1
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done

(env01)$ conda install /installers/anaconda/cassandra-driver-3.11.0py36_1.tar.bz2
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

Now I'm able to install the package without connecting to the internet.